# Executing a script inside a docker container gives no errors but does not work either

Tags: docker, ubuntu, exec

I have a docker container with the basic ubuntu image. I use the following command to start it.

```
docker container run -it -d -v c:\Git\ENGINE_LIB_DIR:/ENGINE_LIB_DIR:ro --name ibuntu ubuntu
```

inside the mounted volume is a Java JDK and a script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/ENGINE_LIB_DIR/jdk/" >> ~/.bashrc;
echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/ENGINE_LIB_DIR/jdk/bin/" >> ~/.bashrc;
exec bash
```

So it basically adds the mounted java to the path to make it useable. This script works, as long as I am executing it from the ubuntu bash inside the container. If I try to use

```
docker exec -it ibuntu sh -c "sh /ENGINE_LIB_DIR/action.sh"
```

from outside the container it does not give any error message, whereas

```
docker exec -it ibuntu sh -c "java -version"
```

Returns "java: not found". So I suspect the script is not executed properly. I tried absolute paths, just without "sh -c" and basically any other method I found by googeling.

My goal is to easily use a java jdk provided inside a docker container to build a project. I am gladful for any help.

Edit:
I tried the /bin/bash -ic approach from @itachi. It still says java: not found, while the shell call gives back that error:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
sh: 0: Can't open ./ENGINE_LIB_DIR/action.sh
```

Edit 2:
I managed to narrow the behaviour down to the `docker exec` command. I setup the container with `docker container run -it -d -v c:\Git\ENGINE_LIB_DIR:/ENGINE_LIB_DIR:ro --entrypoint /ENGINE_LIB_DIR/action.sh --name ibuntu ubuntu /bin/bash`. The java path variable is functioning when attached to the container, but when i execute `docker exec ibuntu sh -c "java -version"` it still says `sh: 1: java: not found`. I would be grateful for any idea.

Comment: Try using `/bin/bash` instead of `sh` (although `sh` is probably aliased to `/bin/bash`), and invoke this with `-i` flag which makes bash interactive (it should load `~/.bashrc`). So your command to test is: `docker exec -it ibuntu /bin/bash -ic "java -version"`.

Comment: @itachi I tried your suggestion with both, the java -version test and the shell execution. The "java -version" still says not found, but the script call gives me the error as shown in the edit on the main post

Comment: I highly recommend reading the official [Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  Trying to set up a container by injecting a bunch of host things on to a plain image isn't a typical use of Docker.  I'd suggest never using a base `ubuntu` image anywhere other than the `FROM` line of a Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for that suggestion. I am aware that this is quit atypical. We are actually in a stage where we are testing a setup for a clients needs that requires that way.

For the solution, the action.sh is not needed as the -e argument in docker run can provide the needed environmental variables. This did not fix the docker exec issue tho.